# Can I create a modal with a dynamic id?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, modal-dialog

I have been trying for a while now to create a modal window that opens with dynamic id's that are generated in php. The id's are all stored within a database and called when needed to create a user table.

I want to be able to click on a user and have all of their settings and options appear in the modal window, although as I have said above I want one modal that opens the correct information for the user depending upon which users has been clicked.

I have the current code displaying the users:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { echo "
<table class='table table-hover'>
  <tr style='font-size:18px;'>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Username</th>
  </tr>"; // output data of each row while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "
  <tr style='font-size:16px;'>
    <td><a href=\ "#id=$row[username]\">".$row["name"]."</a>
    </td>
    <td style='color:#3c9bce'>".$row["username"]."</td>
  </tr>"; } echo "</table>"; } else { echo "There are 0 clients in the system matching your search criteria";
```

and I have tried the following to get the modal to open.

```
<div id="#id=$row[username]">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="header">
      <h4 style="text-align: center;">Use the map below to select the closest agent to the breakdown</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
      <p>THIS IS A MODAL</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cf footer">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Am I using the wrong id for the modal?

Comment: Have you tried doing `#id$row[username]`? I don't think div with id `#id=something` is valid

Comment: Ahhhh I see, yeah I shall try that

Comment: Note that I have removed `=` sign from your id. Also, does php renders the correct id? Shouldn't it be something like `#id<? echo $row[username] ?>`

Comment: Will you have multiple modals (with dynamic ID) open at a time?

Comment: One modal at a time will be open, but the content within the modal will have to be dynamic, I realize now as I am typing this that I may have just found the answer to the problem and may have been over complicating things!

Comment: I was going to say, if indeed it is only one at a time, then you can just populate that modal over and over again with your data. But OK, great. Hope it works out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this using a bit of jQuery/Ajax.

```
$(function() {
     $(document).on("click", "#editData", function () {
     var list = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $('#containerData').html('');  
        $.post("process.php",{list:list},
            function(data){
                $('#containerData').html(data);
             });

         });
     });
```

and in **process.php**

```
//do whatever you need with the data
$id = $_POST['list'];
echo $id;
```